# Does this audio connector exist?

Tags: audio, splitters

I am looking for any consumer-audio (1/4 or 1/8 inch, mono or stereo) 3-way cable that could be described as a 'T' splitter rather than a 'Y' splitter.  The intended use is to be able chain multiple 'T' splitters on top of each other without putting extra physical strain on the cable portion (rather than the metal connector).

I did not find such a cable in my searches and wonder if anyone else has come across one.

[image: T splitter example]

Comment: So you're essentially looking for a Y splitter that has an "extension" channel and a "branch" channel rather than two "branch" channels? At least that's how it makes sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use something these, feedthru RCA adapters with a side connector:

http://www.aliexpress.com/item/10PCS-RCA-adapter-RCA-Male-to-female-to-Female-M-F-F-Connector-Adapter-Audio-3/32469466648.html?spm=2114.40010308.4.167.2LWvQi

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/2pcs-Audio-Right-Angle-RCA-Copper-Adapter-Splitter-1-Male-to-2-Female-Gold-Tone-/191495690255

Daisy chain the barrels and add extension cables from the side connectors.

Comment: Note that these are RCA adapters.  You'll need an adapter plug or two to use them with standard 1/4" or 1/8" headphone/speaker jacks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  This is better than what I found, and not unusable, but also not ideal for my use case, as it is FM-F rather than FM-M and RCA is a bit awkward.  If all else fails I guess I will use those adapters and combine them with some other adapters.

Comment: I have not seen such a thing for mini plug connectors. What is the signal freq. range? Signal level?

Comment: Line level audio

Comment: Then I would use individual L/R cabling, if it is not too cumbersome. It really depends on the physical requirements since you are worried about cable strain.